# How do I pass a range on another sheet within the spreadsheet file to a custom function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I know how to pass simple ranges to a custom function (ranges in the same sheet as the function usage). How can I pass the address of a cell in a **different sheet** to that function. For example
A1 has `=myfcn(othersheet,row(a1),column(a1))`

and function `myfunction(sheetname, rownum,colnum, cells)`

I only need to pass the address of **one** cell of the other sheet.

Comment: Please clarify your question: what relation is there between myfcn and myfunction? One has three arguments, the other four. And what is different about cells being on another sheet? Certainly, the commands like row() and column() apply just as well to other sheets: `=row(Sheet2!B5)` returns 5, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ANOTHER sheet name is `Sheet2` and the cell that you want to refer is A2 then the reference to be used should be `Sheet2!A2`, then the resulting formula is

```
=myfcn(Sheet2!A2,row(a1),column(a1))
```